# Dask cluster compatibility with orchestrators

Tags: cluster-computing, dask

I was wondering how compatible Dask is with cluster orchestrators other than Kubernetes.  In particular, I am interested in Marathon and Nomad.  From my research, Nomad doesn't seem to address Dask at all, although it claims to be agnostic, being able to handle "anything."  Marathon does have a GitHub project named dask-marathon, however it hasn't been updated in 4 years, and it specifically states that the project is a proof of concept onlym with no guarantee of quality or future maintenance.  Any words of wisdom here would be greatly appreciated, since I do not want to use Kubernetes at this point.

Answer (score 0):

For options on how to deploy Dask I recommend looking at the setup documentation: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup.html

You're correct that the marathon project hasn't been updated in a long while.  There have been some other dask+mesos projects in the past.  I don't know how active they are though.